# Jest testing promise in React gives TypeError: Cannot read property 'finally' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, jestjs

I have a child component `MySummary` that calls the function passed from the parent component like this:

```
submit() {
    this.setState({submitting: true});
    this.props.handleSubmit()
      .finally(() => {
        if (!this.mounted) {
          return;
        }
        this.setState({submitting: false, showConfirmDialog: false});
      });
  }
```

And in the parent component the `handleSubmit` function returns a `promise` and redirects on submit to another page:

```
handleSubmit() {
    return this.gateway.submitExam()
      .then((exam) => {
        this.setState(exam);
        this.props.history.push('/exam/result');
      });
  }
```

In browser it seems to be working. And even though I thought `finally` would never been called because we redirect to another page, and the child component would be unmounted then, it seems that it still reaches that block of code. I have logged into console from the `finally` block when I was running that code. So I am not sure how is that happening. The problem I have is that my test is failing and that I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'finally' of undefined

In my test I am clicking on a button that calls the submit function, and then I am just checking if the handleSubmit function was called:

I am mounting the component like this:

```
< MySummary exam={exam} handleSubmit ={jest.fn()}/>
```

And this is the test implementation:

```
const submitButton = confirmDialog.findByProps({'data-testid': 'submit-exam'});
submitButton.props.onClick();
expect(mySummary.props.handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

But, that test gives the error mentions above. I assume the error comes from wrong implementation of the prop `handleSubmit`, which is only defined as `jest.fn()`. How can I mock the promise implementation so that I can get this test to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need your mocked function to return a `Promise`, like the actual function does. So, try setting the mock's return value to a resolved `Promise`:

```
handleSubmit={jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve())}
```

See [An Async Example](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async.html) and [Mock Functions](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html) from the Jest docs for more info.